# Store block from YAML file and append it in a existing YAML file using Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have most of the code where I read each file and dump to a new file. 
My next step is to store car1 (from mom, file2) and add it under dad block as car2, file1).

```
------
File 1
------
dad:
  car1:
    model: [toyota-venza]
    awd: true
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: true
        version: 1.35 
    mileage: 54,025
    year: 2000
age:
  ...

------
File 2
------
mom:
  car1:
    model: [toyota-camry]
    awd: false
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: false
        version: []
    mileage: 20,241
    year: 2013
age:
  ...
```

Where the new file will look like this... containing car1 and car2 for dad.

```
dad:
  car1:
    model: [toyota-venza]
    awd: true
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: true
          version: 1.35 
    mileage: 54,025
    year: 2000
  car2:
    model: [toyota-camry]
    awd: false
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: false
          version: []
    mileage: 20,241
    year: 2013
```

Comment: By what criteria do you mean to match `car2`? Is it always the first key of the first key? Your input file is no [valid YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/), your `version` is misleadingly indented

Comment: For car 2, I guess I would want the block that contains car2. Yes, it should be the first key of the first key. Sorry for the bad indent...

Comment: Your examples are not valid YAML. Your `version` is indented two spaces with regards to its sibling key `backup_camera` and that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you kind find the car information by using key 'car1', you can search the toplevel mapping for a value with that key:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap
import glob

dad = CommentedMap()
dad['dad'] = d = CommentedMap()

for idx, file_name in enumerate(sorted(glob.glob('car*.yaml'))):
    data = yaml.load(open(file_name), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
    for k in data:
        if 'car1' in data[k]:
            new_key = 'car{0}'.format(idx+1)
            d[new_key] = data[k]['car1']
            d.yaml_add_eol_comment('# from {0} in {1}'.format(k, file_name),
                                   key=new_key, column=30)

print(yaml.dump(dad, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper))
```

gives you:

```
dad:
  car1:                       # from dad in car1.yaml
    model: [toyota-venza]
    awd: true
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: true
        version: 1.35
    mileage: 54,025
    year: 2000
  car2:                       # from mom in car2.yaml
    model: [toyota-camry]
    awd: false
    option:
      nav:
        backup_camera: false
        version: []
    mileage: 20,241
    year: 2013
```

Assuming the data in files `car1.yaml` and `car2.yaml`. I used [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)¹ here, to use ordered maps on which you attach comments.

You can do this with PyYAML, but you will loose the guaranteed ordering, and the comments:

```
import yaml
import glob

dad = dict()
dad['dad'] = d = dict()

for idx, file_name in enumerate(sorted(glob.glob('car*.yaml'))):
    data = yaml.load(open(file_name), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    for k in data:
        if 'car1' in data[k]:
            new_key = 'car{0}'.format(idx+1)
            d[new_key] = data[k]['car1']

print(yaml.dump(dad, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper))
```

---

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) of which I am the author.</sub>

Comment: dad = CommentedMap()
dad['dad'] = d = CommentedMap()

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to get the package to install because I have Centos 5.1.  What is the equivalent of dad and d if I used pyyaml?

Comment: @user3203920 how did you install? Using `pip install ruamel.yaml`? I'll make a PyYAML downgraded version and edit the post.